# SFDX versioning error for leadsource field

Tags: community, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

I have account,contact, opportunity,case and lead in my unlocked package. 
For case entitlements,multicurrency fields (ex. currencyisocode, slastartdate, entitlementid etc.) I have added ""features": ["ENTITLEMENTS", "MULTICURRENCY"]" in project-scratch-def.json file and running versioning command with "-f config/project-scratch-def.json".

In this case I am getting errors for contact record type "Contact.Record type name: Picklist value: Facebook in picklist: LeadSource not found".
I am Not able to identify the issue here. what could be the issue for this error?

**Note:** I am doing versioning for unlocked package. I have added standardvalueset for leadsource picklist in my package and all values are available there. If I am removing those feature related fields and running the versioning command without "-f config/project-scratch-def.json" then its versioning is getting success everytime.

Comment: Picklist values have to be enabled for each Record Type, otherwise a value might be missing. I'm not sure how to work this out in a scratch org situation though

Comment: picklist values are enabled and available for each record types

Comment: Also assuming you have FLS/CRUD rights to `Contact.LeadSource`?  Not sure what else to check here

Comment: Hi Brian, I am doing versioning in production org and I have read only access for my profile. Is it causing the issue?

Comment: What kind of packaging are you doing?  Unlocked Packages or Managed packages?  Namespacing?  If you can update your original question with those details, it'll help. I personally am not sure what else to look for

Comment: Its for unlocked package. In general the versioning is succesfully done with out adding the features in scratch json file. updated the question. please check.